# Microsoft Visual Studio Change Default Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, themes, microsoft-metro

I am finding it really hard to code using the **black theme** given in the `visual studio 2012` IDE. Is there anyway i could get back the older grey theme or is there anyway i could make it look a bit more whiter ?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Color Theme

or you could try to use [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MatthewJohnsonMSFT.VisualStudio2012ColorThemeEditor) , it has pre built themes too.

Comment: Anything for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: same menu allows three options, Dark, Light and Blue. I'm finding Light easiest to read.

Comment: Thanks- Could I add another Theme?

Comment: add Vamsi Katakam's picture to your answer! (or some picture of it... makes it most clear)

Answer (score 13):

**For Visual Studio 2015 and later versions**

Tools->Options->General->ColorTheme

Change theme and Press OK.

[image: Visual studio options window]

Comment: this is the same as the current accepted answer... but you added a pic... so... I'm conflicted